# get hex of BitmapDescriptorFactory color in Android

Tags: android

How can I get the hex value of BitmapDescriptorFactory colors in android?

e.g. what is the hex of this:

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE
```

Comment: what do u want to do ?

Comment: I use the above to set a market on a map with a certain color. I want to in my XML layout set other elements to the same color. Maybe there is a way to get the above value in XML?

Comment: u want to set a maker with the colour u want to set on the map ?